# How to hide tag div for CPT when it's empty in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, custom-post-type

For posts I used the codes below to hide the tag div when it's empty:

```
<?php
   if( get_the_tags() ){
    echo '<div class="keywords"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> KEYWORDS: <a href="#">';
      the_tags( ' ', ', ');
    echo '</a></div>';
   }
?>
```

But now I've got another custom post type named "team", but I have no idea how to hide the div if there's empty since the way it calls the tags is different from the way above...here's the codes I have now:

```
<div class="keywords"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> KEYWORDS: <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'team' ) ?> </a></div>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you can do it in the same way. Why not?

Comment: thank you, I am not familiar with php codes...don't really understand those terms....but I've tried the same way and it works!!

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it!!

```
<?php
  if( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'xiriblog-tag' ) ){
    echo '<div class="keywords"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> 關鍵字 <a href="#">';
    echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'xiriblog-tag' );
    echo '</a></div>';
   }  ?>
```

Or, by using a variable:

```
<?php
  $term_list = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'xiriblog-tag' );
  if( $term_list ){
    echo '<div class="keywords"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> 關鍵字 <a href="#">';
    echo $term_list;
    echo '</a></div>';
   }  ?>
```

Comment: Well done! I don't know if `get_the_term_list` is a heavy function that does a lot of processing, but you might consider storing the result in a variable. That way, you only need to execute the function once, after which you can  check its value, and later echo its value. I took the libery to add that variation to your answer.

Comment: The other snippet uses two variations of the same function, `get_the_tags` and `the_tags`. It looks like the first returns a value, while the latter echoes (outputs) the value itself. So maybe there is also a function called `the_term_list`, with which you could build the solution like that, although personally I'd prefer to use only one function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the alternative way to solve my question!! It's a great lesson to me